# Archive Validation failed Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, archive

I m trying an iOS app public release in Xcode 8  but get error validation failed:

[image]

Comment: Just press previous and send again, sometime Apple's authenticating got problem

Comment: I've had an try but get error

Comment: how many time you get this error?

Comment: i have try two to three after this message and get to success uploading app

Comment: i have try many times but getting error.Thanks

Comment: nice screenshot. I think you should make a valid project which passes the validation – that is going to solve the current issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try by uploading application loader.
goto Xcode > Open Dveloper Tool > Application Loader

Comment: i m also trying in Application Loader but there process loading and Authentication compiling long time but not upload.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with provisioning profile. Remove old provisioning profile and add again, then it would work on both Xcode and application Loader.
You can see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66014